# How to handle missing features in a sample while doing predictions?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, feature-engineering

I'm interested in generating predictions during **inference** phase (not during training) where a few features are missing.

The problem statement and my implementation is:

- I have a tabular dataset of 26k samples with 17 features(some categorical and some continuous).
- A lot of the samples(around 3k) were missing multiple feature values.
- I used a variety of methods to do the imputation. For instance, grouping by the target variable and then replacing the **NaN** with group mean/mode depending upon the category of the variable.

```
df["danceability"] = df.groupby("music_genre")["danceability"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

- Here , **music_genre** was the target, and **danceability** had float values & some of      those were missing.
- This way, all the missing values got removed.
- After that, I trained an **XGBoost** Classifier with Grid search.
- But, now I am serving this model as a flask application where I need to respond with **predictions** to all the requests. Requests can be a **batch**(set of samples) or a **single sample**.
- The problem is that the samples in the request have some **missing features** and still, I have to generate the predictions because it is expected of me to do that.

How should I go about it?

Comment: You can maybe use the rest of the features to predict the missing value??

Comment: Actually, during inference, multiple features might be missing! So, should I train multiple models first for them to generate any feature given the other ones...

Comment: Yupp but that sounds like a lot of work xD

Comment: I thought this would be a trivial task in the ML community. But, when I started to explore, I found 2-3 resources where people were just as confused as me. I think I need to change the approach even while training! The last resort would be to fill missing data by global stat measures!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is, while training you can randomly remove values from certain features and then replace it with some custom value of your own (this value you can use to fill the missing feature value during inference).

So suppose one of your training row is: `x1,  x2, x3, x4, y` where y is your target variable, now you can randomly replace one of the feature values and in the process generate one more training row. Say we replace x3 with a new value X3. So the new training row will be `x1,  x2, X3, x4, y`. During inference if the value of x3 is not there, I will simply fill it with the value of X3. Hope this makes sense.